# Information about logging system in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to find information about logging system in kafka, what logs write to `controller.log`, `log-cleaner.log`, `kafka-request.log`, `state-change.log`, `server.log`, `kafka-authorizer.log`.

I didn't find it kafka documentation and by googling, what i find is how to load logs into kafka.

I need some description for this logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what logs write to ...

You mean classes? Those are all listed in `log4j.properties`

- `server.log` - main broker process
- `kafka-request.log` - Kafka protocol network requests on the broker
- `controller.log` - controller of the cluster
- `log-cleaner.log` - details topic-log rotation and compaction events
- `kafka-authorizer.log` - generated from Kafka ACL authorization events
- `state-change.log` - Not sure, but source code seems to indicate it is a subprocess of monitoring the Controller state